How to insert an image to MySQl with using API
In short. I need to insert an image into the database. But after a year, you can't specify the BLOB type, and the image won't fit in byte[], right?
Example of the Image class
@Id
private Long idImage;
private Long idRoom;
private String date;
private String time;
private ???? imageData;
private String imageType;

What should I do then? Or is there a more efficient way to add an image to MySQL
